# A sequence of zeroes of an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is analytic on $C$ and the set of zeroes of $f$ contains the sequence $$a_n=\begin{cases}n & 4\not\mid n\\1/n & 4\mid n.\end{cases}$$

Is it correct to say that $f$ is a non-constant?

Comment: Won't it contain a sequence of zeroes with a limit point (namely, $1/n$ for $4\mid n$)?

Comment: The subsequence $a_n→0$ for $4|n$ only. Is it sufficient to conclude $f=0$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope! Note that the set of zeros of $f$ has a limit point. Since $f$ is entire, this can only happen if $f$ is the constant $0$ function.

Comment: ....thanks..My only doubt is that having a limit point is sufficient to say $f=constant=limit point$ ?

Comment: Rather, if $f$ is entire and the set of zeros of $f$ has a limit point, then $f(z)=0$ for all $z$. See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem), under "An Improvement."